# reloaddata doesnt seem to be working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I may be using it incorrectly but i think i have it right. I load data into my UITableViewController like so.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
                [cell.textLabel setText:@"Click to add new rower"];
                cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            break;
        case 1:
                [cell.textLabel setText:[[appDelegate teamRoster]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And everything works fine, i then push the user to a different viewController and allow them to enter their name into a text field. I take their name and add it into the same array that populated my UITableViewController, and from the UITableViewController i call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

But nothing happens. If i check my array i can see that it has the correct number of objects, and their name is the last entry, but the tableview remains unchanged...

I was thinking maybe i just dont know how to use reloadData, but from what i have been reading elsewhere this should be working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is self.tableView pointing to the tableView? The most common mistake is that tableView is nil here. And also, check that numberOfRowsInTableView: returns the right number of rows.

Comment: @james Dunay : is you array is of NSArray or NSMutableArray?

Comment: self.tableView gives me this : 2011-06-20 11:07:16.578 CoCoach[27028:207] <UITableView: 0x681de00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x5e39ec0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>    So i think its all good, however when i try to count my array program quits. post code in a second

Comment: Ok @PengOne has shown me the correct way to NSLog the number of items in an array, and it returns 4 times before I enter a name and 5 items afterwards

Comment: Although now that i look at the NSLog again, the last item i enter does not have "" around it where the 4 that I init the array with do have them, could this be an issue?  2011-06-20 11:19:12.768 CoCoach[27142:207] (
    "rower 1",
    "rower 2",
    "rower 3",
    "rower 4",
    james
)

Comment: @James: To me, this indicates that the problem may be with the code that adds to `appDelegate.teamRoster`. Could you please post the relevant bits of that?

Comment: Just to make sure i had it right i switched it from adding in user entered text to just adding my name. Same idea though, -(IBAction)submitAndSendBack:(id)sender{
 CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 SelectedTeamRoster *teamRoster = [[SelectedTeamRoster alloc] init];
 
 [[appDelegate teamRoster] addObject:@"james"];
 [appDelegate.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 
 [teamRoster reloadTableView];
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSLog crashes because you are using the wrong formatter type (@"%@"), it should be:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[[appDelegate teamRoster] count]);
```

Other than that, where is reloadData being called from?  Make sure it's happening on the Main thread.

Comment: where is the main thread? I am running it from inside the UITableViewController class. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Where in the UITableViewController class are you calling reloadData?  Is it viewWillAppear?

Comment: Im calling it from a custom function, -(void)reloadTableView{
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}  Do i need to be calling it from elsewhere?

Comment: I would put it in - (void)viewWillAppear, this way it always refreshes right before the screen displays.  This would at least ensure you aren't calling it out of order.

Answer (score 3):

Your crash is due to the fact that you are doing

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[appDelegate teamRoster] count]);
```

when you should be doing

```
NSLog(@"%d",[[appDelegate teamRoster] count]);
```

Using `%@` sends the objec the message `description`, which does not work for `int`s (or `float`s or `BOOL`s).